# Change Segmented Control Background Image in Swift

Tags: image, swift, background, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to use an image as a background of my Segmented Control.

Which is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way while I was posting the question. I share it with you in case anybody needs.

```
segmentedControlName.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)
```

Comment: If it's correct? Yes, it works perfect for me, but maybe there's a cleaner way

Comment: So please tick your answer yourself.

Comment: I tried but says that I can't do it the first two days. I guess that is to give the chance to other developers to offer alternatives to my own answer. And obviusly if somebody offers something better I will tick that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for subview in (sender.subviews as! [UIView]) {
   if (subview.isSelected) {
     subview.backgroundbackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
   } else {
     subview.backgroundColor = nil
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Hey mate, Thanks for your answer. But what I was looking for was to use an image as a background, not just a color. 
Thanks anyway